# Rails 4 gem rails4-autocomplete 1 letter suggestions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete

I am using gem [rails-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete), but It shows suggestions only after 2 letters, is there a possibility to display suggestions for 1-letter long searching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is! Just add `'min-length' => 1` in your search form like:

```
<%= form_tag terms_path, method: 'get' do %>
  <%= autocomplete_field_tag :search, params[:search], autocomplete_term_phrase_terms_path, 'min-length' => 1 %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```